# Change QFrame Box color and border when pressed

Tags: qt, c++11, qtstylesheets, qt5.4

I'm trying to change a QFrame with a Box style color and border when the mouse pressed down on it. The style is within an external style sheet file. I have the :hover pseudo state working for this but trying the :pressed or :selected doesn't seem to work or show the style changes I want.

Comment: Have you try to use `QPushButton` with `setFlat(true)` to work with *:pressed* and *:selected* ?

Comment: Provide a minimal example of your work, please, in order to get a closer look at your problem.

Comment: Decided to replace the QFrame with a QSplitter instead because the separator allows a :pressed and :hover pseudo state.